# Android ToggleButton clear-ish on older versions?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-togglebutton

I am making an app that uses a ToggleButton, and I am making sure it works on older devices.  On my GS4 (Running Android 5+), it looks like this:

[image]

On my GS3 (Running Below Android 5), however, it looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?  If it is hard to see, the bottom button is sort of clear, while the top button is a solid color.

**NOTE:** I am using AppCompat.

**EDIT:**
`<ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dataToggleButton"
                android:id="@+id/dataToggleButton"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textOff="@string/dataToggleButtonOff"
                android:textOn="@string/dataToggleButtonOn"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="dataToggleButtonChange"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:elevation="6dp" />`

Comment: The bottom one is a 3d button, the top is flat.  That's to be expected-  using the default themes 5.0 switched to a new look- material design which features flatter elements.  So this isn't a bug, its expected.  If you don't like how it looks, write your own.

Comment: Are you talking about the shape of the button?  I'm talking about the color.

Comment: Both.  The entire look of the button was changed.  That color with the flat look on 5.0+ is part of material design.  Prior to that they went with a 3d looking button and a lower contrast.

Comment: It looks weird with a normal button next to it, as it is solid in older versions of Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToggleButtons` (on/off buttons) aren't in the Material design guidelines. They still work in the newer APIs (so far), but their styling is inconsistent across the different API levels.

[Material design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/selection-controls.html#selection-controls-switch) encourages [`Switches`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html) to be used instead. With the AppCompat support library, the styling is supported and consistent across SDK levels, including the older levels.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="@string/some_label"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON"
    app:showText="true" />
```